# Uncertainty about the use of services in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have one question about using of services. I'm creating services in this way 
and everything working properly. Here is my code.

```
var appName = angular.module('appName', ['configuration', 'angularSpinner']);

// this is whay that I creating services. 
(function (module) {
    var moduleName = function () {
        return function(inputVar) {
                // some work with 
        // inputVal variable 
            return result;
        }
    };

    module.factory("moduleName", [moduleName]);
}(angular.module("appName")));


// in this way I'm using service into controller. 
appName.controller('controllerName', function($scope, moduleName) {

});
```

My question is do I need to set 'moduleName' in 'appName'. Ie like this:

```
var appName = angular.module('appName', ['configuration', 'angularSpinner', 'moduleName']);
```

In both cases everything works properly. I would appreciate any comments and recommendations.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question is do I need to set 'moduleName' in 'appName'. Ie like this:

No you do not, unless you actually create another module. In this case your moduleName is actually your factory name. If you wanted to create another module you would do this.

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);

myModule.factory('myFactory', [function(){ /* factory definition */ }]);

var app = angular.module('app', ['myModule']);
// this will now make myFactory available to my app
```

Your using the factory method which returns a function. If you need a service (a singleton object) then use the service method.

I create my services like this

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.service('myService', [function(){

    var serviceMember = { name: 'something' };

    var serviceMethod = function() { };

    // revealing module pattern
    return {
        serviceMember: serviceMember,
        serviceMethod: serviceMethod
    };

}]);
```

Comment: Thank you. You taught me something.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You needed

```
var appName = angular.module('appName', ['configuration', 'angularSpinner', 'moduleName'])
```

The 'appName' is Main Module name, and the 'moduleName' is sub module name. If you put the 'moduleName' with 'appName', then you can call 'modulname' functions wherever you use the 'appName'.

**Main Module :**

```
angular.module('appName',
```

**Sub Module :**

```
, ['configuration', 'angularSpinner', 'moduleName']
```

The concepts works by [Dependency Injection](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) Concept

Comment: Yes. But why it working when I miss to set 'appName' into array?

Comment: You don't need srt appName into the array. it's a main module. The concepts look like a Dependency Injection

Comment: I find it interesting. So the question is - to add ot not new crated services? :)

Comment: Sorry i can't get you'r question. oops